# Is _VERSION the only global variable left in Lua 5.1?

Tags: lua

Puzzled by the Lua 5.0 documentation references to things like `_LOADED`, `LUA_PATH`, `_ALERT` and so on (that I could not use in Lua 5.1), I discovered all of those have been removed and the functionality put elsewhere. Am I right in thinking that the only one global variable left in Lua 5.1 is `_VERSION`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs seem to think that's **almost** the case....

> _G
>       A global variable (not a function) that holds the global environment
>   (that is, _G._G = _G). Lua itself does
>   not use this variable; changing its
>   value does not affect any environment,
>   nor vice-versa. (Use setfenv to change
>   environments.)

It looks like there's also _PROMPT and _PROMPT2, but only when using standalone lua interactively:

> If the global variable _PROMPT
>   contains a string, then its value is
>   used as the prompt. Similarly, if the
>   global variable _PROMPT2 contains a
>   string, its value is used as the
>   secondary prompt (issued during
>   incomplete statements). Therefore,
>   both prompts can be changed directly
>   on the command line or in any Lua
>   programs by assigning to _PROMPT.

Comment: That's from http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-_G for reference's sake.  The same page also mentions the use of _PROMPT and _PROMPT2 in the standalone interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't open ***any*** libs, there's also `_G`, `pairs`, `ipairs` and `newproxy`.

Comment: pairs and ipairs are functions available globally, not variables.  not sure about newproxy.

Comment: All functions are values, and often stored in variables such as the global variable pairs.